# NASM compiler error while making bootloader

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm, bootloader

I am making a bootloader in assembly,  and i got a compiler error while compiling my file in NASM.
the output is:

```
bootloader.asm:1: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
bootloader.asm:16: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+orphan-labels]
bootloader.asm:23: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+orphan-labels]
```

can anybody help? this is my code:

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7C00]

MOV SI, BOOTLOADERSTR
CALL PrintString
JMP $

PrintCharacter:
MOV AH, 0x0E
MOV BH, 0x00
MOV BL, 0x07

INT 0x10
RET

PrintString
next_character:
MOV AL, [SI]
INC SI
OR AL, AL
JZ exit_function
CALL PrintCharacter
exit_function
RET

;DATA
BOOTLOADERSTR db 'it-is-OK Bootloader for OpenKasrix' , 0

TIMES 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
DW 0xAA55
```

Comment: Likely your editor (I'd guess you are on Windows?) is saving as UTF-8 with a byte order mark. What editor are you using? Your editor may have the option to save a plain text (ANSI) and not UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> bootloader.asm:1: error: label or instruction expected at start of line

I cannot reproduce this first error with `NASM version 2.11.08`, so there must be another problem like a [BOM (Byte-Order-Mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding). So check if the first bytes do match one of the sequences mentioned in this article - and if so, remove them (with a Hex-Editor or Saving-Options or ...). Then this otherwise unrecognizable error should magically disappear.

The next two errors are missing a `:` at the end of your labels

```
PrintString      ; line 16
exit_function    ; line 23
```

Add a colon at the end and the errors will disappear. So they should look like

```
PrintString:     ; line 16
exit_function:   ; line 23
```

Comment: ok, thanks for the colon thing. but i am using version 2.13.03, and the thing on the first line must not be working. i was using NASM installed in a folder i extracted from a zip file, but i also have the software version. maybe that would work?

Comment: I would be surprised if there were that great differences in the syntax between these two versions. But I have another surmise: is there a [Unicode byte-order-mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) like `FE FF` at the beginning of your file? You can check that with a hex-editor or the `xxd [file]` command.

Comment: by the way, i'm using windows, and that's, unfortunately, a UNIX command. +zx485

Comment: Ok. That's no issue. Then use a Hex Editor or something similar to check if there's a BOM (Byte-Order-Mark)  at the beginning of your file. These are notorious for creating hard-to-detect errors.

Comment: ok...so i am using a hex editor, and it gave me a bunch of hex code. but now i dont know what to do.

Comment: OK, that's easy. Check if the first two/three bytes of the file (upper left corner) do match any patters mentioned in [this WikiPedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding).

Comment: oh, it has a byte order mark. the first byte says EF.

Comment: **BINGO:** Your first three characters do match the `UTF-8[a]` representation. So your (supposed) text file has a BOM which was surely created by your editor and is confusing the NASM compiler.

Comment: Now get rid of the first three bytes and you're done (=the first error will disappear).

Comment: The easiest way would be telling your editor to omit the BOM. But I don't know how that could be done with your editor, so you have to search the options for something like "BOM/Byte-Order-Mark/UTF-encoding...".

Comment: i tried to delete the hexes with the hex editor, but when i saved it, it just kept the three hexes and changed [BITS 16] to TS 16].

Comment: hmm... maybe change the encoding?

Comment: Yes. Either change the encoding or replace the first bytes with `20 20 20` in the hex editor.

Comment: +zx485 well, changing the encoding to ANSI and then compiling it worked...thanks!